# Adding comment to vimeo videos in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, vimeo

In my ios app when i try to add comments to vimeo videos using video.comment.addcomment, if the comment is only one word it is adding properly, but if it is more than one word it is saying an error that invalid signature.The code i used is:

```
NSString *new = [NSString stringWithString:commentis];
    new = [new stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
NSString *url12 = @"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.comments.addComment&video_id=123456&comment_text=good";
url12 = [url12 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"123456" withString:videoplaying];
url12 = [url12 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"good" withString:new];

NSURL *urlinfo = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url12];
OAMutableURLRequest *request3 = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:urlinfo consumer:consumer token:tokenfi realm:nil signatureProvider:nil];
```

i dint understand the error.the json response i am getting is

```
{
err =     {
    code = 401;
    expl = "The oauth_signature passed was not valid.";
    msg = "Invalid signature";
};
"generated_in" = "0.0124";
stat = fail;
}
```

but if i give the comment as single word it is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it has something to do with the `whitespace` and the way you are executing your request. Make sure there is no whitespace in the `URL` you are formatting.

Replace the whitespace with the URL escape code right before you use the string to create a `NSURL`. Like this:

```
url12 = [url12 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

Comment: To be specific, the error was replacing spaces with plusses. OAuth 1 requires the signature and querystring to use RFC3986, http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986, which changes spaces to %20